# Regarding reading a textbox on current slide in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm new to VBA and have a question about reading the text box in the current slide in a PowerPoint presentation in VBA.  I have some code, but it does not work and I do not know how to debug in presentation mode.  I would appreciate any helo you can give me as this is really important.  Thank you!

PS: I'm working on the Mac

```
Sub answer()
    Dim myInput As String
    Dim sld As Slide
    Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
    myInput = sld.Shapes(4).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    A = InputBox(prompt:="Your Answer:")
    MsgBox (myInput)
    If A = myInput Then
        MsgBox ("Correct!")
        ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow _
        .View.GotoSlide Int(Rnd * _
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Count) + 1
    Else
        MsgBox ("Sorry, try again...")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value myInput is getting in the Msgbox?  You should be able to set a breakpoint (F9) on the myInput line and step through the code (F8).

Comment: Either a line is highlighted or an error number is given when this throws an error. Kindly detail either of the two mentioned. This will help us further in debugging your code. :)

Comment: I don't know where that is though?  How do you operate the step into function of the code?  Also where do you find that @BK201

Comment: It only says: that there is no active powerpoint presentation...

Comment: It doesn't highlight anything when it says that?

Comment: @BK201 It just highlights: Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

Comment: I'm also working on Mac if that makes a difference...

Comment: This confuses me. I tested on my end and it's working. I've even deleted shapes while my presentation is ongoing and it reflects in real time. Would you mind sharing this online? Just want to check it out of curiosity. Use wikiupload or the like. :)

Comment: Here you go:  http://www.4shared.com/file/5N5X2CMjce/Entomologuy.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use

Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

If you are in slide show mode.

Use

Set osld=SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide